# Solve Matrix with Multiple RHS

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave

I have a problem where I need to solve linear equations. The matrix is the same, but the rhs changes (during an iterative procedure). The only way I could see to do this without repeating the matrix factorization is like:

```
[L,U] = lu(A);
x = U\(L\b);
```

This seems clunky. Is there a better way? Can I use LU factors that are stored in a single array? TIA

Comment: so, to make sure I understand, in the equation `Ax=b`, you have a changing `b` and want to solve for all `b`'s?

Comment: Do you need the `L` and `U` matrices for any operations other than solving the system? Does each new `b` depend on the intermediate solutions `x`?

Comment: Yes, this is an iterative procedure where b is constantly changing, but A does not change. I don't need L and U. In fact, I think it is clunky that I have to use them to accomplish what I want to do. Doing x = A\b over and over again would not be efficient, because A would be refactored every time.

Comment: I have read the "\" operator is smart enough to know that L and U are triangular in my code, so it does a simple forward and back substitution.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the last part of your question. Yes, each new b depends on x. This is just a successive substitution type of iteration, i.e. guess x, calculate b, solve for new x, get new b, and on and on .....

Comment: How big is your `A`? How often do you run this? Is `A` sparse? Have you profiled `A\b` vs. `U\L\b`?

Comment: Why is `x = U\(L\b);` clunky to you?

Comment: A\b would work just fine, since A is not so big for current computers. However, this is a demonstration code, so I would like to do it the "right way", i.e. without wasting cycles. The code with L and U makes sense but it is not nearly as clear as A\b, or something like C = lu(A) and x = C\b, but I don't know how to tell it that C are LU factors. It would be nice if I could pass a flag to mldivide that tells it "C is a factored matrix".

Comment: If it's for a demo, I'd say code for clarity and use `A\b`. In general, efficient code hardly ever is "clear" or "obvious" compared to the more "naive" way of implementing it. Then again, if it's for a demo, you might want to make 2 versions; one with `A\b` and one with `U\(L\b)` and a simple `tic...toc` to also demonstrate that it matters greatly to think about such matters :)

Comment: You might even want to opt for `inv()` in this case -- it's clear and fast, but perhaps not accurate to the 12ᵗʰ digit.

Answer (score 1):

Given a system

`LU*x = b`

where `L` is a lower triangular matrix and `U` is an upper triangular matrix.

From your question I understand that the vector `b` is changing constantly and you would like to keep the `LU` factorization constant for all possible vectors `b`.

In other words, if you have `n` different `b`'s you would like `n` different solutions with the same `LU` decomposition of `A`.

I would use forward substitution where you solve a system

`L*m = b`

and then backwards substitution with

`U*x = m`

More [here](https://algowiki-project.org/en/Forward_substitution).

This way you keep the factorization constant for every vector `b`.

And concerning the other question, yes, it is possible to store the `L` and `U` matrices in a single matrix. Just recognize that the diagonal of the `L` matrix is not relevant because it is always `1`.

Comment: This is what I am doing already. It would be much cleaner to just invert and mulltiply the right hand sides over and over again. But, of course, matrix inversion is much less efficient, but probably better than doing A\b over and over again, when A does not change.

Comment: And the second part. Yes, I know I can store the factors in a single array, but how can they be used in a solution? If I do A\b how can it know A contains the LU factors of the original matrix?